# How do I make it difficult to commit a change to a specific file in git repo?

Tags: git

This is the scenario:
I have special file in a git repo, that contains tokens that need to be replaced before the project is being built, and restored back to its "template form" right after the build is complete.

The problem is, that the build process might be interrupted in the middle, and the file may stay in its modified state, and then someone might accidentally commit it. So this is what I want to prevent. I would like the commit to fail, unless the user knows what he is doing (for example, it may be legitimate to add or change a token every once in a while) and maybe "force" the commit somehow in that case.

Is there some mechanism in git that would help me protect the file in such scenario?

Comment: The usual approach is to have a template committed and gitignore the actual file used by the process.

Comment: Do not add temporary files to gits. It seems that we need add such token file into .gitignore.

Comment: Is it possible to add a file that is tracked by git to .gitignore?

Comment: If you have script/build code to restore the file, then you indeed should not have the file in git at all, but instead have a "template" or "master version" with different name, and copy that at the beginning of the build process, instead of restoring it after. That being said, not sure why're getting the downvotes here... Anyway, to improve the question, you might add details like just how you restore the file at the end of the build process.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of the commentators. I would go for something like that, unless someone would suggest a better solution:

Create a template, and commit it to git. Every time the build starts, another file with the tokens replacement will be created from the template (or truncated, if it is already exists from a previous failed build), and this one will be used during the build process.
This generated file will be ignored inside ".gitignore"